# How to alphabetize all of the rows in a CSV file, column by column?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I have a three-column CSV file, like this:

```
chips@food@f
pizza@food@f
tiger@animal@a
fish@animal@a
marshmallow@food@f
New Years@festivals@f
```

I need to alphabetize the rows, first by column 3, then column 2, then column 1. The output would be:

```
fish@animal@a
tiger@animal@a
New Years@festivals@f
chips@food@f
marshmallow@food@f
pizza@food@f
```

How can I sort the data in this manner?

- Some columns contain UTF-8 data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `sort` command:

```
$ sort -t@ -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 input.csv
fish@animal@a
tiger@animal@a
New Years@festivals@f
chips@food@f
marshmallow@food@f
pizza@food@f
```

Comment: The power and simplicity of Unix can not be matched!I was just finishing writing the exact same answer when you posted yours :)